# After SETUP runs and Outlook Add-in is installed, how to enable the Add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2003

Q. How to "find" and "enable" an add-in after installation

**Background**

I developed an add-in which targets Outlook 2007. I used C#, VSTO 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010. It runs fine when started from Visual Studio; it also runs fine against Outlook 2010.

Using the Publish Wizard of VStudio 2010, I created a SETUP.EXE in a "publishing folder".

I wanted to try this add-in against Outlook 2003 (it would be a bonus of this could work against that platform too).

On the machine with Outlook 2003 installed, I ran the above SETUP and this install ran fine without errors:

- .Net Framework 4 Client Profile (x86
  and x64) downloaded and installed
- VStudio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime
  (x86 and x64) downloaded and installed
- MS Office customization was
  successfully installed

So, what to do now? I've researched this and I cannot find this recently installed add-in anywhere:

- Nothing about this add-in in
  Tools-Options-Advanced Options-Add-In
  Manager
- Nothing about this add-in in
  Tools-Options-Advanced Options-COM
  Add-Ins..
- Nothing about this add-in in
  Registry:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\
  Outlook\Addins

The UI that should be exposed is a button on the Office CommandBar.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's very simple. With VSTO 2010, you get a new runtime which cannot target Office 2003. [See this MSDN blob article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/04/15/upgrading-vsto-projects-to-use-with-visual-studio-2010-navneet-gupta.aspx). There are also here on StackOverflow some discussions about the necessity to build two solutions (Office 2007/2010 vs. 2003).

Comment: Thanks - I had a hunch this might not be possible and this is a big help.